# Repaint masonry window sill

Tags: painting, paint, exterior, masonry, sill

Our house has a Victorian bay window and what appears to be chunky masonry/concrete window sills. They look like they are painted with some form of gloss which has become flaky and green over the years.

I want to repaint it and after either stripping or sanding I want to know what paint to use. I was going to buy some good quality masonry paint to use to paint the walls of our house (combination of brick/render) and wonder if I can use the same paint on the windows sills?

But masonry paint sometimes looks thinner than gloss paint and I wondered if should I buy some proper masonry gloss paint (if that exists?)

Thanks.

Comment: I've decided to strip the paint off using a hot air gun which seems to be working, so now I will have the plain masonry. From looking at other houses, the gloss paint seems more solid and the masonry paint seems to  pick up dirt more than the gloss paint.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Acrylic/Latex: Because concrete is porous, a water-based or acrylic primer is more likely to soak into the concrete than an oil-based primer, bonding to the substrate and allowing the paint to grip the surface. These primers will also reduce the dust on interior concrete.

Answer (score 0):

Yes this paint is out there go to a masonry supply they will hook you right up it will be oil base so get the proper cleaning agent for your brushes and rollers.